# Azure Scheduler (Preview) vs Cron Jobs + Web Role?

Tags: azure

I just came across a new Azure feature - Azure Scheduler:

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/11/10/windows-azure-scheduler-service-part-i-introduction/

I was wondering - from an architectural perspective - how is this any better or different from using an online CRON service to send a predefined request to a WebAPI endpoint?  I'll need a WebAPI endpoint in both cases - with the Azure offering, I have the ability to Enqueue into an Azure Queue, but otherwise it's the same thing, right (maybe with the former being cheaper)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two big differences with the scheduler service

- Managed and paid for within the same Azure subscription. This does make ops a little easier.
- The RESTful API for the service.

As good as it may be, it is expensive compared to other offerings in the market (I use setcronjob). As you point out, you still need to write your job endpoint anyway.

Comment: Thanks Simon - I've seen answers of yours all over the place.  If you don't mind me asking something related - Cron + Endpoint is pretty much always going to be better than a `while(true)' worker role, right?  Is that approach even used anymore?

Comment: While (true) worker roles is still the correct pattern for reading queues (and other things that you need to be continuously monitoring). Cron + Endpoint works if you have scheduled jobs, but if you need to read the next items off the queue, and always be checking if there is something, then a worker role is fine.

Comment: I see, makes much more sense now.  Thank you :)

Comment: @SimonMunro Are you still using setcronjob? if so is it still the best cron scheduling service in you opinion?  if not what service would you recommend ? I'm using cron-job.org at the moment but I need to set jobs programmatically now.

Comment: @jasan we now use the Azure scheduler. That is mainly for billing and 'enterprise' reasons (same logins etc). Setcronjob is remains a good service, although the scheduler built-in to Azure (not available when this answer was written) has free and low-cost options that are probably better suited.